# how does the pine-script strategy.position_avg_price function work

Tags: pine-script

can someone enlighten me, please.

On the code below, Does the input line default to "1" or does the "step" argument change the result (to decimal)? in the end what is the result?

long_tp_inp = input(100, title="Long Take Profit %", step=0.1) / 100 //what does step ?

Then what is the result of the command below:
strategy.position_avg_price * (1 + long_tp_inp)

thank for help

Answer (score 0):

It is percentage of the initial `strategy.position_avg_price`.

If  `long_tp_inp` is `100`,  then your `strategy.position_avg_price * (1 + 100/100) = strategy.position_avg_price*2`, so your exit/entry will be at price higher by 100% of the current price.

Example:

```
//@version=4
strategy("My Strategy", overlay=true, margin_long=100, margin_short=100)


long_tp_inp = input(100, title="Long Take Profit %", step=0.1) / 100 
price = strategy.position_avg_price * (1 + long_tp_inp)    
plot(price)


if bar_index == 1
    strategy.entry ("LONG", true)
    
strategy.exit("EXIT", "LONG", limit =   price)
```

Comment: Hello and thank you for your response.
So as I understand it, if the asset's price is 1000 Eur and "long_tp_inp = 100".

strategy.position_avg_price * (1 + 100/100) = strategy.position_avg_price * 2 = 1000 * 2 = 2000 Eur
So I exit / return to position at the price of 2000 Eur?

Comment: Correct. I've updated answer with example.